# iOS model layer notifying Controller Object

Tags: ios, xcode, model-view-controller

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

At the above link, I see the following in regards to how the model layer should communicate with the ViewController.

"When a model object changes (for example, new data is received over a network connection), it notifies a controller object, which updates the appropriate view objects."

**My question is, how does the model object notify the Controller object?** What are various ways this can be done? My model layer gets the user's location and then calls a web service. How should I notify the controller object when that data is downloaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, depending on your specific case. Generally you would use a protocol/delegate implementation, key value observing, or notifications. There is a pretty good overview [here](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/).

**Edit:**

Thought I should add, as the comment to this answer mentioned: using callback blocks is also a very solid option, depending on your needs. There are a lot of possible deciding factors on what solutions are best for what cases but here is a general outline I follow.

If you are guaranteed to only need one observer at a time: I generally use blocks or delegates. My personal preference is that I use blocks if there are only one or two callbacks because this is where they shine, but I use delegate protocols if there more than a few possible methods.

If you may need multiple observers, I use notifications via `NSNotificationCenter`.

I use Key-Value-Observing when I only need to observe specific properties on an instance, instead of events.